# Mapping functions

Tags: functions

> Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers. Define $f : S \to S$ by
>   $f(1)=2$, $f(2) =3$, $f(3) =1$, and $f(s) = s$ for any other $s \in
> S$. Show that $f \circ f\circ f = i_s$. What is $f^{-1}$ in this case?

I do not know how to do this. I take that $i_s$ is the identity?

Comment: Yes, $i_S$ is the identity function on $S$, so that $i_S(n)=n$ for all $n\in S$.  You can find $f(f(f(1))),f(f(f(2))),f(f(f(3))),f(f(f(4))),\ldots$ using the definition.  Can you find a function $g$ such that $f(g(n))=n$ for all $n$, by "undoing" $f$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Would $g$ then be identity or will it be just $f$ itself?

Comment: Q.matin: No, neither of those.

Comment: @Q.matin what about $g = f^2$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer So, you are asking if there is a function $g$ such that $f(g(n)) = n$ . Then the only possible way I can think of that happening is if $f(f(n)) = n$. Can you provide more hints?

Comment: @jim I dont quite understand how $g = f^2$? Why would that be the case?

Comment: @Q.matin: Part of the definition of the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is that $f(f^{-1}(n))=n$ for all $n$.  So $f^{-1}(n)$ should be the thing that $f$ sends to $n$.  (Its definition has already been given in the answers since my comment.)

Comment: @Q.matin: Because $f(f(f(n)))=n$, if you consider $g(n)=f(f(n))$, then $f(g(n))=n$.  That is, the inverse of $f$ happens to also be $f\circ f$.  (jim is using the exponent to mean composition of $f$ with itself.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer Ah that is what I meant on my very first comment. I just forgot to put the inverse sign there. Thanks a lot for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that this map is both injective and surjective, and thus bijective, and therefore has an inverse.

To find the inverse, you just look at the function "backwards".  Since $f(3) = 1$, we may say that $f^{-1}(1) = 3$, and similarly $f^{-1}(2) = 1$ and $f^{-1}(3) = 2$.  For any other $s \in S$, we see that $f(s) = s$, and applying $f^{-1}$, we see that $f^{-1}(s) = s$.

To show that $f \circ f \circ f$ (call it $f^3$), we must show that for all $s \in S$, $f^3(s) = s$.

To do this, look at where the first power of $f$ sends any element $s$.  For $s \in S - \{1,2,3\}$, what happens?  Can you generalize this to any other powers?

For $s \in \{1,2,3\}$, simply apply $f$ three times ("by hand"), and see what you get!

Comment: Thanks!! And how will I show that $f \circ f\circ f = i_s$?

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that part.  I'll edit.

Comment: @Q.matin: By finding $f(f(f(n)))$ for each $n$.  Where did you get stuck in your attempt?  For example, do you know how to find $f(f(f(1)))$?  (Work from the inside out.  There are 3 steps.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer I couldnt attempt it because I didn't know where to start.

Comment: @Q.matin: Start by finding $f(1)$.  Then find $f(f(1))$. Then find $f(f(f(1)))$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I got for $f(f(f(1))) = 1$ is that correct?

Comment: @andybenji I did $s \in \{1,2,3\}$ by hand like you said and got that it equals 1, is that correct?

Comment: @Q.matin: Yes (regarding your comment to me).  You get $2$, then $3$, then $1$. Similarly for $2$ and $3$, and the rest are easier. No (regarding your comment to andybenji).  Recheck $f(f(f(2)))$ and $f(f(f(3)))$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oh so then I must get three different answers to andybenji question? So then the answer will be 1,2 and 3?

Comment: @Q.matin: Yes, those are the results, but I cannot tell from your comment if you understand how to show that the results are $1$, $2$, and $3$, respectively.  (Again, to find $f(f(f(2)))$, you first find $f(2)$, then use that to find $f(f(2))$, then use that to find $f(f(f(2)))$, for example.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yup, that is what I did to find them. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose the inverse of $f$ is $g$, then $g(1)=3$, $g(2)=1$, $g(3)=2$ and $g(s)=s$ for all $s \in S$.